# Why does xcode Source Control menu show duplicate Working Copies?

Tags: xcode, git

My Mac OS X project is under local git source control.

I created a new branch a few days ago.  Now when I click the Source Control menu, the first few menu items are as follows:

```
Working Copies  
myProject _ myLatestBranchName  
myProject _ myLatestBranchName  
Checkout...
```

I don't understand why I have duplicate items under Working Copies.

Why is this happening? I'm using Xcode 5.1

Comment: Did you discover anything about why this happens?

Comment: Did you duplicate, copy/paste, move or rename folders in this project before seeing this issue?